# Multiple sliders in interactive octave plot

Tags: user-interface, slider, octave

I am trying to create a GUI where multiple variables could be modified using sliders. This is my example this far: I'm trying to alter the gradient of a linear function by summing two sliders.

I am completely new to the gui of octave and matlab, so I assume there is some fundamental error.

```
%%%%%% In file myplot.m %%%%%
function myplot

  %% Create initial figure and spiral plot
  figure;  
  axes ('position', [0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6]);
  global t;   
  t = linspace (0, 100, 101)
  x = t;
  y = t;
  plot (x, y);  
  axis ([-100, 100, -100, 100]);

  %% Add ui 'slider' element      
  hslider = uicontrol (                    ...
         'style', 'slider',                ...
         'Units', 'normalized',            ...
         'position', [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1], ...
         'min', -100,                         ...
         'max', 100,                        ...
         'value', 0,                      ...
         'callback', {@plotstuff}          ...
       );
  %% Add ui 'slider' element      
  kslider = uicontrol (                    ...
         'style', 'slider',                ...
         'Units', 'normalized',            ...
         'position', [0.1, 0, 0.8, 0.1], ...
         'min', -100,                         ...
         'max', 100,                        ...
         'value', 0,                      ...
         'callback', {@plotstuff}          ...
       );
end

%% Callback function called by slider event
%% Also in file myplot.m (i.e. a subfunction)
function plotstuff (h, k, event)
  global t;
  n = get (h, 'value');
  m = get (k, 'value');
  x = t;  
  y = (n+m) * t ;
  plot (x, y);  
  axis ([-100, 100, -100, 100]);
end
```

This is my error message:

㎫ >> error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 0x0, op2 is 1x101)
error: called from
octave_test>plotstuff at line 43 column 5
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 0x0, op2 is 1x101)
error: called from
octave_test>plotstuff at line 43 column 5

This is the figure window:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```matlab
function plotstuff (h, k, event)
```

This signature is wrong. First argument to the callback function is a handle to a slider object. Second argument is the event. There is no third argument. This is the correct form:

```matlab
function plotstuff(h, event)
```

In this callback, `h` equals either `hslider` or `kslider` (the numbers returned by `uicontrol`).

You have multiple options here. You can make `hslider` and `kslider` global, as you did with `t`, and use them to get the slider values in the callback:

```matlab
%% in myplot
global hslider kslider
...

%% in plotstuff
global hslider kslider
...
n = get (hslider, 'value');
m = get (kslider, 'value');
```

If you don't want to use global variables, you can pass the two handles as additional arguments to the callback:

```matlab
%% in myplot
hslider = uicontrol(...)
kslider = uicontrol(...)

set(hslider, 'callback', {@plotstuff, hslider, kslider})
set(kslider, 'callback', {@plotstuff, hslider, kslider})
```

Then you can use these arguments in `plotstuff`:

```matlab
function plotstuff (handle, event, hslider, kslider)
    n = get(hslider, 'value');
    m = get(kslider, 'value');
```